# On SvelteKit load functions, why the change between assigning a type to `load()` normally vs using `satisfies`?

Tags: typescript, frontend, sveltekit

From what I can remember, SvelteKit docs have shown two different ways of assigning a type to `load()`. This applies to both server and client loads.

Method 1

```
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async () => {
// ...
};
```

Method 2

```
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load = (async() => {
// ...
}) satisfies LayoutServerLoad;
```

I remember the docs had the first method, then it switched over to the latter, and then back again to the first method (not sure if the last change was after `1.0`?).

I am new to Typescriptt (dev in general). I did do some research on `satisfies`, and I believe I understand the flexibility it gives over the conventional way.. but what is the reasoning behind the back and forth in regards to `load()` implementation?

Comment: Look at the commits and PRs that changed it